# How do I convert this string to a DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How do I convert a string like `"1319556419"` to a `DateTime` in C#?

Comment: What's the expected result of this conversion?

Comment: What is the meaning of the string? Is it a unix epoch time? Without knowing what the string _means_, no one can help.

Comment: sounds like something asked on here many times before....

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: `"1319556419"` is not a recognizable date. Voting to close.

Comment: @PhonicUK I wouldn't edit extra information into the question like that. At the moment the answers say that the string _looks like_ a UNIX timestamp; it _might_ be something else, but editing the question takes that chance away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like a UNIX timestamp, if so it'll be:

```
Int64 timestamp = Convert.ToInt64("1319556419");
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddSeconds(timestamp);
```

edit: It's actually seconds instead of milliseconds by the looks of it.

This gives the date of October 25, 2011.

Comment: +1 http://ideone.com/25jDcW

Comment: I think your base time should be `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)` but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Regarding the edit. Many UNIX systems use an `Int32` (signed 32-bit integer). So `int timestamp = int.Parse("1319556419");` is natural. If the source has switched to 64-bit UNIX time, it's safe to use the code as it stands now in any case. See [Year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).